# How to convert block producers long string vote information into Scaled votes?

Tags: accounts, block-producer, voting, private-blockchain, producers

In my blockchain, there are 4 accounts registered as block producers. `accountnum1` vote for each of them.  `cleos system listproducers` returns

```
Producer      Producer key    Url                          Scaled votes                
accountnum1   key1            https://accountnum1.com      0.2500
accountnum2   key2            https://accountnum2.com      0.2500
accountnum3   key3            https://accountnum3.com      0.2500
accountnum4   key4            https://accountnum4.com      0.2500
```

I need this information using `Eos-sharp` API. I tried following c# code to get it:

```
var prodList = await r.GetProducers(new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.GetProducersRequest()
{
   json = true,
   lower_bound = "1",
   limit = 10
});
```

This returns Vote information for each producer account as `5775596249181922304.00000000000000000`. How can I convert it into simplified one as `Scaled votes` `0.2500`?

Comment: You can use the producers table on the eosio system contract https://www.bloks.io/account/eosio?loadContract=true&tab=Tables&account=eosio&scope=eosio&limit=100&table=producers

Comment: But this also returns ```"total_votes": "5775596249181922304.00000000000000000"```.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total vote weight

```
curl -sd '{"scope":"eosio", "code":"eosio", "table":"global", "json": true}' http://api.eosn.io/v1/chain/get_table_rows | jq '.rows[0].total_producer_vote_weight'
```

Then you can divide each row in th producer table by that number to get the fraction

```
curl -sd '{"scope":"eosio", "code":"eosio", "table":"producers", "json":true, "limit":10000}' http://api.eosn.io/v1/chain/get_table_rows | jq '.rows[] | "\(.owner) \(.total_votes)"'
```

I'm not familiar with the EOS-Sharp library, but presumably there is a GetTable() method or similar.